# Connecting Kindle Fire (1st Gen) to Wi Fi using Connectify

Tags: wireless-networking

I setup a hotspot on my laptop using Connectify-Pro. Kindle Fire (1st Gen) is able to see the network, and when I type in the password, it shows 'Obtaining IP Address'. At the same time, Connectify on my laptop also shows that Kindle is trying to connect. But then, Kindle Fire throws me an error that it cannot connect the the network. Can someone help me out?

Regards.

Edit: I switched from Connectify to Virtual Wifi Router and now everything works like a breeze.

Comment: Be sure you are using a supported 802.11 band/versions.  If you are broadcasting 802.11N then depending if its 2.4ghz or 5.0ghz would determine what other bands/versions are supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I overcame this issue by installing Virtual Wifi Router instead of Connectify